# Добавить шумы на аудио

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, синтезатор-речи

У меня есть простенький синтезатор речи на `Python3`, написанный с использованием библиотеки `gTTs` (Google Text To Speech). Однако, несмотря на все мои старания, синтезированный голос все равно часто легко можно отличить от человеческого. Как можно добавить шумы на аудио так, чтобы голос стал более-менее похожим на человеческий и при этом остался распознаваемым?

Comment: Распознавание речи базируется на статистическом анализе верно? Статистика - отбрасывает шумы. Как вы представляете решение вашей задачи? Вы хотите соотношение полезный сигнал - шум - 1:100 сделать?

Comment: @nick_n_a нужно сделать так, чтобы синтезированный текст распознавался человеком и при этом он бы не понял, что это именно синтез.

Comment: Может вам пойти другим путём - найти диктора - надиктовать предложений и отдельных слов, и связать несколько аудио в один? Я думаю что с робототекста - более вменяемую речь вы не сделаете. И шум тут непричём.

Comment: @nick_n_a тут трудная ситуация, нужен бот, который сможет синтезировать абсолютно любой русскоязычный текст.

Comment: это хорошая докторская - на нобеля. Незнаю есть ли у какой-то фирмы хорошая платная версия такого - но это должно стоить хороших денег, и легко не делается. Даже робот София говорит немного тормознуто.

Comment: @nick_n_a прошу-таки по существу :)

Comment: Максимум что я (и думаю другие) могут посоветовать - надиктовать побольше словарь, возможно с несколькими вариантами прочтения слова.

Comment: @nick_n_a я просто хочу в ущерб качеству аудио добавить эффект большого помещения, эха и всего того, что могло бы сделать звук не таким четким.

Comment: эхо - это сложение двух и более одинаковых аудио (можно даже по-среднему арифметическому)  с сдвигом по фазе от 0.01 до 3 сек.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887862/python-chorus-effect-and-meaning-of-audio-data

Comment: Поищите примеры програмный примочек "echo" еффект "chorus" и "delay" (для звука, для гитары). И поменяйте заголовок вопроса - на "Добавление еха в аудио" например, или что-то такое. Больше шансов на ответ будет.